# Is it possible to upload the image according to the gender given to the customer?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In the project, I have a dropdown of Gender in which I have 2 option Male And Female.

There are two column on a single page for 2 customers and I want to upload the images for both of them.

Is it possible to upload the image according to the gender given to the customer?

I have given male gender to first customer and female to the second customer

There are 2 clicks before the window open to select the image and I am using ubuntu that is why I am not able to send the location of the image in the window.

Please help how can I do it for 2 tines for 2 customer

I want the help in the tool or the approach which I can use to achieve this goal.

Note:  I am using Ubuntu  os

2 click code after which select image windows open:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#displayed-photo-modal-security-243202797")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#photo-modal-file-upload-input")).click();
```

code of click for save button:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#photo-modal-save-button")).click();
```

path of image:

```
/home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg
```

Html for 1 click

```
<a id="displayed-photo-modal-security-243202797" class="securityCard_link text-hide set-photo-target" href="#photo-modal" data-show-tip="show" data-container-image="" data-toggle="modal" data-type="Security">Add</a>
```

html for 2 click

```
<input id="photo-modal-file-upload-input" class="uploadFile photo-modal-upload-photo" type="file">
```

html for save

```
<a id="photo-modal-save-button" class="btn-cta btn-primary close-photo-modal" data-dismiss="modal" title="Save" data-button-type="submit">Save</a>
```

Comment: Can you add some details of the code ?

Comment: hi @Prany please see the updated question

Comment: and HTML please as well

Comment: hi @Prany please check

Comment: You've posted code for 3 clicks but you don't clearly explain what the actual problem is. Please update your question and restate the question.

Comment: Please see comment on prany answers

Comment: No, you need to edit your question and add all the relevant info there. People aren't going to search all the comments and all the comments on all the answers to find all the info that should have been in the question.

Comment: All the information is in question sir let me know what you need more please I'll edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Ubuntu OS I an not able to upload the picture, I will be doing this task on windows OS because It is easy on Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can try below in Ubuntu as your home folder is available in home/administrator

```
File image= new File("/home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg");
image.createNewFile();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(image.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("#photo-modal-save-button")
```

Comment: do you mean like this? driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#displayed-photo-modal-security-243202797")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#photo-modal-file-upload-input")).click();
File image= new File("/home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg");
image.createNewFile();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#photo-modal-save-button")).click();

Comment: it is not working because when it opens the windows to select the image it opens  up m,y eclipse-workspace default  and there is no place to write the location. Help

Comment: Try by adding file://home... to the file name

Comment: I don't understand @prany

Comment: File image= new File("//home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg"); you mean like this @prany

Comment: Like this file://home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg

Comment: it gives me an error that no such file or directory but the location is correct.

Comment: ok, can you show me your code how are you managing the upload image of the file. I think I am not able to understand your question properly

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#displayed-photo-modal-security-243202797")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#photo-modal-file-upload-input")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    File image= new File("file://home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg");
    image.createNewFile();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#photo-modal-save-button")).click();

Comment: sorry sir for not making the question clear i am just a beginner in automation

Comment: Thats ok, everyday is new day to learn something new :) . Please check my updated answer for you

Comment: sir the code goes to the next element but the file is not yet get uploaded.

Comment: sir can you update the new code where do i have to use this

Comment: sir  there is a error add cast and when I add cast it tells me to change the cast back

Comment: Like this sir: File image= new File("/home/administrator/Downloads/aaa.jpg");
    image.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(image.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.Print("<a>");

Comment: bw.write("<a>") and also try the one for which I updated the answer

Comment: sir its not working and also it deletes every photo which path i mention in code.

Comment: will you prefer to upload the picture from windows by autoit? or you think we should debug this problem? because from Windows it is very easy

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804286/trouble-with-filewriter-overwriting-files-instead-of-appending-to-the-end

Comment: sir i am not able to get the solution for this . I know this is easy on wiindows.