# While loop overwriting other inputs

Tags: java

Whenever I put inputs into this loop, no matter how many it will only write my final input to the file
Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

class lista {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        File productList = new File("productList.txt");
        FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("productList.txt", true);

        /// While Loop Start

        while (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the product:");
            String product = n.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter the price:");
            String price = n.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter the type of product, e.g. Movie, Bluray, etc...");
            String type = n.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(product + " - " + "$" + price + " (" + type + ")" + "\n\n");
            try {
                fr.write((product + " - " + "$" + price + " (" + type + ")" + "\n\n"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Type \"0\" if you would like to stop, type \"1\" if you would like to continue.");
            int y = n.nextInt();
            n.nextLine();
            if (y == 1) {
                x = 0;
            } else {
                x = 1;
                fr.close();
            }
        }
        /// While Loop Ends

    }
}
```

I can input something like,
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,1
3,3,3,0
, and it will only print:

```
3 - $3 (3)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use 'append' instead of 'write'

Comment: Please show the correct input data and/or review your use of `nextLine()`; that code will only loop once.

Comment: @carlossalzar doesn't work.

Comment: @KenY-N if I input three of any strings, then type one, the loop will start again.

Comment: works OK for me

Comment: *and it will only print:* - where are you printing - maybe this is wrong?

Comment: Can you show your actual inputs?

Comment: @HeanzyZabala I inputed:
```Enter the product:
God of War

Enter the price:
9.99

Enter the type of product, e.g. Movie, Bluray, etc...
Game

God of War - $9.99 (Game)


Type "0" if you would like to stop, type "1" if you would like to continue.
1
Enter the product:
Castle in the Sky

Enter the price:
16.99

Enter the type of product, e.g. Movie, Bluray, etc...
Bluray + DVD

Castle in the Sky - $16.99 (Bluray + DVD)


Type "0" if you would like to stop, type "1" if you would like to continue.
0```
This is one of the examples

Comment: @HeanzyZabala It will only write Castle in the Sky - $16.99 (Bluray + DVD) to the file, the other input gets completely disregarded

Comment: @ScaryWombat It keeps multiple inputs written in the file?

Comment: @Seco01I tried your inputs, and it works fine for me. I got all of the products printed in the text file.

Comment: *It keeps multiple inputs written in the file?* - yes, make sure you are looking at the correct text file - check the timestamp etc.

Comment: @HeanzyZabala I think it's my export then, I exported it into a executable jar. Any ideas on settings to fix to make the Jar run like in IDE?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please remember: never put such details into comments. Always look at your question before submitting, and think "are all the details in there that people will need to fully understand what I am doing" ....

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of [Trouble with filewriter overwriting files instead of appending to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804286/trouble-with-filewriter-overwriting-files-instead-of-appending-to-the-end).
However you seem to have found the solution yourself already (the `true` parameter when creating the FileWriter). This should append to the file instead of overwriting it. If this does not work, then you might have a problem with the file or the OS. In any case, your code is not fundamentally wrong and should work.

Some suggestions for readability and ease of use on the code itself (just minor details).

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
PrintStream out = System.out;

try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("productList.txt", true)) {
    INPUT_LOOP:
    while (true) {
        out.println("Enter the product:");
        String product = in.nextLine();
        out.println();

        out.println("Enter the price:");
        String price = in.nextLine();
        out.println();

        out.println("Enter the type of product, e.g. Movie, Bluray, etc...");
        String type = in.nextLine();
        out.println();

        String entry = product + " - " + "$" + price + " (" + type + ")" + "\n\n";
        out.println(entry);
        writer.append(entry);

        out.println("Type \"exit\" if you would like to stop, any other input will continue.");
        if (in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {
            break INPUT_LOOP;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```